# Não estou conseguindo chamar class no css do modo convencional

Tags: html, css

Estou começando  a usar o vs code agora, porém, quando tento fazer referência à uma classe criada no código em html, pelo css, preciso fazer sem ponto, não consigo entender que tipo de erro pode ser esse. segue os 3 códigos(index.html, footer.css e index.css).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>MInha Pagina</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./Assets/css/index.css" />
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <section>
        <article>
        </article>
    </section>
    **<footer>
        <h1 class="text">
           green
        </h1>
    </footer>**

</body>
</html>
```

```css
@import url('./footer.css');
@import url('./header.css');
@import url('./reset.css');
@import url('./section.css');
```

Código que deveria funcionar:

```css
.footer {
   color:green;
 }
```

Código que está funcionando (sem o ponto):

```css
footer {
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: Agora notei, deu tudo certo!

Answer (score 4):

Está correto.

Não irá funcionar com o ponto na frente pois seu html não possui nenhum elemento com `class="footer"`, somente o elemento `<footer>`

```css
.footer { color: red } /* classe */
footer { color: blue } /* elemento */
```

```html
<footer class='footer'>Footer I</footer> <!-- classe -->
<footer>Footer II</footer> <!-- elemento -->
```